# Git compare before Merging 2 branches

Tags: git, github, branching-and-merging

I have 2 branches which say incompatible when I call for pull request on Git Hub. Is there a way I can compare where the conflict is before I can merge the branches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

Go to your branch,

```
git format-patch $(git merge-base HEAD otherBranch)..otherBranch --stdout | git apply --check -
```

otherBranch -> The name of the branch you want to compare with.